# What is the behaviour of STA (0:1) in MIX?

Tags: assembly, taocp

In MIX STA stores the contents of the A register in a given memory location.

I can't see how the behaviour around the sign is covered in TAOCP. How does MIX behave in the following example:

Location 2000 contains:  + 5 4 6 2 1

The A register contains: - 7 8 1 3 2

What does STA 2000 (0:1) do?

Is this thought of as taking the values 3 2 from the A register and putting them in the field 0:1 of memory location 2000? If so, is there an implicit conversion of any non-sign value to a +? Or does the 0 in the field specification mean "take the sign of the A register, and any remaining bytes and put those values into the location"?

Interpretation 1: 2000 -> + 2 4 6 2 1

Interpretation 2: 2000 -> - 2 4 6 2 1

Or is there a third option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes in the definition of `STA`, the `F` field is funky.

Reading Section 1.3.1, **Storing Operations** (p 130 of my Volume 1, Third Edition) I find:

> On a *store* operation the field F has the opposite significance from the *load* operation: The number of bytes in the field is taken from the right-hand portion of the register and shifted *left* if necessary to be inserted in the proper field of CONTENTS(M).  **The sign is not altered unless it is part of the field.** *[my emphasis]*

It gives various examples, where:

```
  Location 2000 contains: | - | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
  Register A    contains: | + | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 |
```

```
  STA 2000(0:1) gives:    | + | 0 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

which is your **Interpretation 2**.

It seems that the `F` field refers to the field in the *destination* word, and:

- if `F` is `(0:0)`:

  - the sign of the source is stored in the sign of the destination,
  - the rest of the destination is unchanged.
- if `F` is `(0:n)` (`n` in `1..5`):

  - the sign of the source is stored in the sign of the destination,
  - the `n` *right-hand* bytes of the source are stored in bytes `(1:n)` of the destination,
  - the rest of the destination is unchanged.
- if `F` is `(m:n)` (`m` in `1..5`, `n` in `m..5`):

  - the `n-m+1` *right-hand* bytes of the source are stored in bytes `(m:n)` of the destination,
  - the rest of the destination (including the sign) is unchanged.

*[It's a long time since I last even considered `MIX`... I confess I had remembered it as too quirky to be useful.  I cannot say that I have changed my mind !]*